# Koszul-Malgrange theorem on non-compact manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

> Does the Koszul-Malgrange Theorem hold on non-compact manifolds?

That is, given a connection on a complex vector bundle over a non-compact complex manifold with a connection whose curvature has vanishing $(0, \, 2)$ part, does this vector bundle have a holomorphic structure such that the $(0,\, 1)$ part of the connection is the Dolbeault operator?

The reason I'm asking is that a number of references (such as https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Koszul-Malgrange+theorem) state that compactness is required, but the original Koszul-Malgrange paper does not seem to (although my French is not amazing), and the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem – from which the Koszul-Malgrange theorem follows straightforwardly – also does not require compactness.

> If compactness is, indeed, required, where is it used in deriving
> the Koszul-Malgrange theorem from the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem?

Comment: All you need to prove is that there exists locally a basis of sections of your vector bundle annihilated by the (0,1) part of the connection. Thus this is a purely local question, you don't need compactness at all.

Comment: You can find a detailed proof in Section 2.2.2 of Donaldson's book "The Geometry of Four-Manifolds". You do not need the compactness.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!